# TypeError: write() takes at most 5 arguments (6 given) Python Excel

Tags: python, excel

I need to input this argument. But python not letting me to input more than 5. Is there a way?

```
sheet.write(26, 0, "Index", center, bold, timeFormat)
```

Comment: which api are you using? xlwt?

Answer (score 0):

You can set multiple format properties by passing a dictionary of properties to the add_format() constructor:

```
format = workbook.add_format({'bold': True, 'align': 'center'})
```

Then, instead of passing 'center' and 'bold' separately, as you did you can call:

```
sheet.write(26, 0, "Index", format, timeFormat)
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'add_format'